# Conditional blocks in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Say I have function `with_foo` that takes a block, and wrap it around a piece of code, like

```
with_foo do
  puts "hello!"
end
```

Now I would like to make the wrapping conditional, like

```
if do_with_foo?
  with_foo do
    puts "hello!"
  end
else
  puts "hello!" # without foo
end
```

Is there any way to write this shorter/more elegantly, meaning without having to repeat the code `puts "hello!"`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

if you are willing to specify argument with a block, it is possible.

given `with foo` above, you can write such snippet:

```
whatever = proc {puts "hello"}
#build a proc object with a block
if do_with_foo?
  with_foo &whatever
#pass it to with_foo
else
  whatever.call
#normally call it
end
```

Comment: looks better than my solution, but I was looking for a way which doesn't even require me to write `whatever` twice. Any ideas?

Comment: @zero-divisor: I added an answer using a bit of meta-programming. I don't think that you can do it directly with the existing infrastructure.

Answer (score 4):

A proof of concept using the proxy pattern:

```
class BlockWrapper
  def initialize(obj, use_wrapper)
    @obj = obj
    @use_wrapper = use_wrapper
  end

  def method_missing(*args, &block)
    @use_wrapper ? @obj.send(*args, &block) : block.call
  end
end

module Kernel
  def wrap_if(use_wrapper)
    BlockWrapper.new(self, use_wrapper)        
  end
end

def with_foo
  puts "with_foo: start"
  yield
  puts "with_foo: end"
end

wrap_if(true).with_foo do 
  puts "hello!"
end

wrap_if(false).with_foo do 
  puts "hello, no with_foo here!"
end
```

Output:

```
with_foo: start
hello!
with_foo: end
hello, no with_foo here!
```

Comment: took me a little bet to get behind the concept but I think I got it now, looks good! Why do we actually need to open the Object class here?

Comment: @zero-divisor: yeah, it's hard to grasp at first, metaprogramming in Ruby may be ugly to implement but it's a joy to use. We need `wrap_if` to be available everywhere (it's a generic feature), so we either add it to class `Object` or to the module `Kernel` (which is included in `Object`).

Answer (score 3):

You can put the duplication code into `Proc` object and pass it to the method as block or call it directly.

```
hello = proc { puts 'hello' }

with_foo(&hello)
# OR
hello.call
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this:

```
def without_foo &pr
  pr.call
end

send(do_with_foo?? "with_foo" : "without_foo") do
  puts "hello!"
end
```

Comment: Which part is not human readable? You do not like ternary operators?

Comment: it's not only the ternary operator (which I do like although I prefer it when making an conditional assignment), it's also the fact that we have to define a wrapping function here which does nothing. Especially in Ruby it's usually possible to write code where you already now what it does after looking at it for one second, and I was looking for such a type of solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
def simple_yielder
  yield
end
def maybe_with condition, with_method
  send( condition ? with_method : :simple_yielder ) { yield }
end

#...

maybe_with( do_with_foo?, :with_foo ) do
  puts "Hello?"
end
```